# how to embed html and php

Tags: php, html

how can we integrate html and php in the given code.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
<tr>
<td><span class="xxxx">User Name</span></td>
<td><span class="xxxx"><input type="text" name="username" id="username"             size="20" value="default value"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="xxxx">Password</span></td>
    <td><span class="xxxx"><input type="password" name="password"     id="password" size="20"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
......
</form>
```

Comment: uh what, you need to expand your question, thanks

Comment: Can you explain pls?

Comment: Where is the PHP you want to "integrate"?

Answer (score 0):

You have clarify us better, without any given info we cannot give our best response.

But **IF** you are trying to embed some content of php inside the html the foundation is like that:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<li>Menu Item <?php echo $i; ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for here seeing how no question is asked. 
If you are looking to turn your HTML code into PHP

```
echo "<form action=login.php method=post >";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span class=xxxx>User Name</span></td>";
echo "<td><span class=xxxx><input type=text name=username id=username size=20 value=default value></span></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><span class=xxxx>Password</span></td>";
echo "<td><span class=xxxx><input type=password name=password     id=passwor" size=20></span></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "</form>";
```

If you are looking to just insert some sort of PHP into your HTML. Notice that the value of the input is PHP while the rest of the code is HTML

```
<td><span class="xxxx"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="20" value="<?php echo (your value) ?>" /></td>
```